# Terraform Module for VMware VMs

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I am creating a module for VM creation in VMware, and I'm looking to clone a VM template.  The hangup is when adding more disks than just the single disk that the template provides or adding a disk in the future if needed.

I don't know if adding another disk section in the virtual machine resource and setting the variable type to map using interpolation syntax would work.

It would be nice if there was a way to use something like jinja for templating.

Module work in progress:

```
data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "${var.vmw_dc}"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "${var.vmw_datastore}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "${var.vmw_cluster}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "${var.vmw_network}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = "${var.vm_name}"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

  num_cpus = "${var.vm_cpu}"
  memory   = "${var.vm_mem}"
  guest_id = "${var.vm_GuestType}"

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 20
  }
  disk {
    label = "${var.vm_disk.*.label, count.index}"
  }
}
```

Doing this as a non-module would be easy. Just have a bunch of resource declarations like the above code, or creating a module and just passing the variables through in module per VM needing created.

The above would work for a single disk VM if you ignore the second Disk declaration. But if I need to add the second disk then a second disk declaration is needed and a third and so on.

So I want to be sure, if creating a map or a list of map variable that contains Disk2 through X, then in the second disk declaration the other disks will get rendered when executing `terraform plan`.

```
"vm_disk" = {
  Disk2 = {label=X,Size=X,Position=X},
  Disk3 = {label=X,Size=X,Position=X},
  Disk4 = {label=X,Size=X,Position=X},
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have written and explain how it doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Edited post to include more information. Just looking if what im thinking is feasible as a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not currently a way to have dynamic amounts of sub resources in Terraform so you can't simply use something like:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ...
  disk {
    count = "${length(var.disks)}"
    ...
  }
}
```

In other providers such as AWS your module could create an instance without any `ebs_block_device` sub resources of the `aws_instance` resource but then use separate `aws_ebs_volume` resources to create separate disks and then attach with the `aws_volume_attachment` resource which, because they are all top level resources, allow you to use the `count` meta parameter to dynamically set the amount of volumes each instance gets.

While the VSphere provider does offer a separate `vsphere_virtual_disk` resource the only way to attach these separate disk resources to a VM is by using the `attach` parameter of the `disk` sub resource so you would be unable to dynamically attach different amounts of disks in your module.

Comment: That what i was getting att. I thought about the sperate virtual disk resouce but like you said still need a disk sub resource with attach, so still same issue. Just picking up on terraform so wasn't sure if was possible in some way.

Comment: You could raise a feature request issue for it or, if you are happy to write Go and know VSphere well, maybe even write a pull request to add a `vsphere_disk_attachment` resource.

Answer (score 1):

Any sub resource in terraform that has the same name, like `disk` and `network` for `vsphere_virtual_machine`, is just an array of objects. So you can change

```
disk {
  label = "disk0"
  size  = 20
}
disk {
  label = "disk1"
  size  = 20
}
```

to something like

```
disk = [
  {
    label = "disk0"
    size = 20
  },
  {
    label = "disk0"
    size = 20
  }
]
```

From there it's pretty easy to see that you could just create a variable or some other logic that builds the array and just assign it to disks.

```
disk = ${var.disks}
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, passing in 'additional disks' as a variable to a custom vsphere module then `concat`ing with a `disk0` local variable.